# C# WCF Channel Timeout on subsequent calls

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I have a C# app calling a Soap client using WCF. The first call to the service succeeds, but any calls thereafter fail.

The code to setup the client is:

```
public WebserviceHelper(string username, string password, string webserviceURL)
{
    var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647;
    binding.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;
    binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
    binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
    binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
    binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);

    var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(webserviceURL);
    var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<EntityAPISoap>(binding, endpoint);

    SoapClient = new EntityAPISoapClient(binding, endpoint);
    SoapClient.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new CustomEndpointBehavior(username, password));

    var isAlive = SoapClient.isAlive();
    Console.WriteLine(SoapClient.State); //Opened
    isAlive = SoapClient.isAlive(); //timeout exception
}
```

The first call to `isAlive` returns immediately, the second call times out with this exception:

> The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after
>   00:01:00.  Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or
>   increase the  SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to
>   this operation may   have been a portion of a longer timeout.

I've increased the timeout, but then it just takes longer to respond and anyway the server responds within a second, so 1 minute is more than enough.

Comment: Maybe calls are being throttled? You essentially perform the same call twice in a _very, very short_ period of time. Try adding a `Thread.Sleep(3000);` after `Console.WriteLine(SoapClient.State);` See if that changes something.

Comment: I've given that a try and no difference. Actually the SOAP service is running locally as well (it's a Java Mule project) and I can call it from other project types without a problem.

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with WCF and Java Mule. It could be caused by how WCF handles [concurrency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193(v=vs.110).aspx#Concurrency) or [sessions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193(v=vs.110).aspx#Sessions%20Interact%20with%20InstanceContext%20Settings). Try to check which concurrency and session modes are being used right now. These settings might cause Timeouts if not set properly for your specific instance.

Comment: Are you running the service in visual studio?

Comment: The service is running in Mule (Java), the client is running in Visual Studio